# Query Fields Dynamically and Retrieve Results per Field

Tags: fields, dynamic

I'm trying to query a record's fields based on a calculated result from another record.  So, if the result is "A", then on State_Mappping__c object I want to query A__c field and get the value.

Executed in Anonymous Window

```
String StateMapID = 'a0323000000n7CcAAI'; //Setting ID
String Result = 'A';
String oquery;
String OwnerField = Result + '_Owner__c'; 
// this should set the A_Owner__c field
oquery = 'Select ' + OwnerField + ' from State_Mapping__c where ID = \''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(StateMapID)+'\'' ;
// Query the A_Owner__c field
State_Mapping__c OwnerMap = database.query(oquery); 

Schema.SObjectType sot = OwnerMap.getSObjectType();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = sot.getDescribe();
Set<String> StateFields = res.fields.getMap().keyset();
system.debug(OwnerMap.valueOf(OwnerField));
```

The current debug result is = "A_Owner__c"

I want it to be the value of the field so I can assign it to a variable and run further queries/code against it.

Comment: Have you tried OwnerMap.get(OwnerField)?

Comment: There is no `valueOf` method on the `SObject` class, nor is it a `Custom Setting` method. Curious that this compiles. What API Version are you using? I can't even compile your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change .valueOf to .get (don't know how I missed this)

Executed in Anonymous Window

```
String StateMapID = 'a0323000000n7CcAAI'; //Setting ID
String Result = 'A';
String oquery;
String OwnerField = Result + '_Owner__c'; 
// this should set the A_Owner__c field
oquery = 'Select ' + OwnerField + ' from State_Mapping__c where ID = \''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(StateMapID)+'\'' ;
// Query the A_Owner__c field
State_Mapping__c OwnerMap = database.query(oquery); 

Schema.SObjectType sot = OwnerMap.getSObjectType();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = sot.getDescribe();
Set<String> StateFields = res.fields.getMap().keyset();
system.debug(OwnerMap.get(OwnerField));
```

ALSO, during my research/testing, I found an alternate method.

```
            State_Mapping__c StateMap = [SELECT  **all fields needed** FROM State_Mapping__c where ID = :StateMapID];

            String[] OwnerMap = new List<String>();
            OwnerMap.add((String)Statemap.get(OwnerField));
            system.debug(OwnerMap);
```